# How can I for each row calculate the sum and write the percentage of that sum near each value

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I have a table:

```
   X1 X2 X3

Y1 10 12 15
Y2 45 5  23
Y3 12 47 56
```

How can I for each row calculate the sum and write the percentage of that sum near each value.
For example:
       X1 percent X2 percent X3 percent

```
Y1 10  27%    12   32%   15 40.5%
Y2 45   ..    5     ..   23..
Y3 12    ..   47    ..   56..
```

Comment: See `prop.table` with `margin = 1` to get the numbers you're looking for. I don't think it should be too difficult to then figure out combining the two datasets.

Comment: Is there a reason you tag your questions with `data.table`? Because none of your questions seem to indicate you're using one..

Comment: @akrun Thank you! Do you know why did I get -1 vote for my question? I am new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use.  If `dat` is the dataset (`dat` is data.frame in this example)

```
 v1 <- paste0(round(prop.table(as.matrix(dat),margin=1),2)*100,"%") #suggested by @Ananda Mahto
```

or

```
 v2 <- matrix(paste0(100*round(as.matrix(dat)/rowSums(dat),2),"%"),3,3)
 cbind(dat, v1)[c(rbind(1:3,4:6))]
 #    X1   1 X2   2 X3   3
 # Y1 10 27% 12 32% 15 41%
 # Y2 45 62%  5  7% 23 32%
 # Y3 12 10% 47 41% 56 49%
```

#### Update

For, 5 rows and 4 columns, the steps are the same.  For example:

```
 set.seed(42)
 dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(5:70, 5*4,replace=T),ncol=4))
 v1 <- paste0(round(prop.table(as.matrix(dat1),margin=1),2)*100,"%")
```

or

```
 v2 <- matrix(paste0(100*round(as.matrix(dat1)/rowSums(dat1),2),"%"),nrow=5,ncol=4)
 n <- ncol(dat1) 
 cbind(dat1,v2)[c(rbind(1:n,(n+1):(n*2)))]
 #     V1   1 V2   2 V3   3 V4   4
 #   1 65 32% 39 19% 35 17% 67 33%
 #   2 66 28% 53 22% 52 22% 69 29%
 #   3 23 20% 13 11% 66 58% 12 11%
 #   4 59 36% 48 29% 21 13% 36 22%
 #   5 47 27% 51 29% 35 20% 41 24%
```

Comment: Thanks! Please, how can I do that when I have 5 rows and 4 columns?