# How can I change the numeration in column with R

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I have a table with column

```
X <- c(6,6,6,10,10,26,26,26,26,26,80)
```

So in X we have 4 unique numbers.

How can I change the numeration for each value? For example: 6,6,6 are on the first place, so make them equal to 1; 10,10 are on the second place make them equal to 2 and so on.

Comment: Since there was no answer to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842753/how-can-i-for-each-row-calculate-the-sum-and-write-the-percentage-of-that-sum-ne#comment38573725_24842753), I've gone ahead and removed `data.table` tag from some of your Q, where I don't see any relevance at all. Could you please not pollute tags? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give a slightly different answer than Richard's if the unique elements do not come in sorted:

```
X <- c(6,6,6,10,10,26,26,26,26,26,80)
as.numeric(factor(X) )
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4
```

Compare:

```
> X <- c(80, 6,6,6,10,10,26,26,26,26,26)
> as.numeric(factor(X))
 [1] 4 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
> match(X, unique(X))
 [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg that would be difficult to determine since the OP didn't mention sorting, just position. `match(x, unique(x))` matches the positions regardless, which is what it seems like they were asking.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I have nothing against your answer, it is indeed a very nice solution, but in programming the rule is that the more general purpose code wins

Comment: ... touché .....hehe.  Weird, I didn't even notice this change since another one of my answers got accepted almost simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with `match`

```
> X <- c(6,6,6,10,10,26,26,26,26,26,80)
> match(X, unique(X))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one more vector very similar to X: y <- c(4,4,4,15,15,40,40,40,40,40,90)  And I need to replace column X with vector Y.

Comment: Okay, just try `data$X <- y`